# Meaning of sentences from an introduction to "The House of the Dead"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, literature

From Julius Bramont's introduction to a 1911 edition of *The House of the Dead* by "Fedor Dostoïeffsky", from [Project Gutenberg](https://gutenberg.org/files/37536/37536-h/37536-h.htm):

> Hence his rage with the calmer men, more gracious interpreters of the modern Sclav, who like Ivan Tourguenieff were able to see Russia on a line with the western nations, or to consider her maternal throes from the disengaged, safe retreat of an arm-chair exile in Paris. Not so was *l'âme Russe* to be given her new literature in the eyes of M. Dostoïeffsky, strained with watching, often red with tears and anger.

What do they mean? Is the first sentence wrong because it lacks a predicate verb? I can’t find one.

Comment: I assume you are referring to Dostoevsky's novel _The House of the Dead_.  These passages look like a very old translation from the Russian; they use outdated transliterations of his and Turgenev's names. Also, "Not so was I'dme Russe" makes no sense whatever and must be a mistake in copying. I suggest you find a better translation.

Comment: Please provide information about the source of these quotes.

Answer (score 1):

"Hence his rage [...modifiers...]." is grammatically a sentence fragment. It's an idiomatic way of saying "That is the reason for his rage".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the person who has edited the question.

[Something mentioned previously] was the reason for Dostoevsky's anger against other writers such as Turgenev, who wrote about Russia in a calm, detached manner.

He wanted to create a new type of literature describing *l'âme Russe* (French for *The Russian soul*) in a more emotional manner.

Answer (score 0):

Hence is strange beast called a conjunctive adverb. It can be followed by a clause, an adjective or a noun.

Rules of punctuation were somewhat different in the 19th century: it was not unusual to use a semi-colon or a full stop before a conjunction.

To understand this sentence fragment, is is necessary to attach it to an abridged version of the previous sentence:

> He wrote with a sacramental fervour ..., hence his rage with the calmer men, ....